# If I have a list of objects, how do I use LINQ to query for a property of those objects in a SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, list, linq

I'm a little new to Linq (C#) so I could use some help. I have a list of objects that is a bunch of records that I have pulled from a SQL Server table.

I need to query a second table from a different database that has additional related info for the records contained in the list of objects taken from the first table and I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

I have an object called `ReportData` that I then need to take certain properties from that first collection and certain related properties from the List from the second table and store it into the `ReportData` objects which will then be used to populate a `.csv` file.

I've got the population of the `.csv` file done, it's just the rest of it that I'm not entirely sure how to tackle.

Comment: Why bring the data back from the SQL Server and then go back to it? Why not `JOIN` the data in the RDBMS first, before bringing it back to the application layer?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with MS SQL but would that require more than read permissions on the database?  All my employer will allow us is read access to the databases that we are pulling the information from because its a critical system and they don't want us to accidentally screw something up.

Comment: A `JOIN` doesn't require more permissions, no. You're simply (in this case) "reading" from 2 objects at the same time.

Comment: For the list of records pulled from the first database, I used the FromSqlRaw method which from my understanding you can't use if you are going to do a table join.  My db experience is limited and ancient and I'm still kind of refreshing myself on it so I might be approaching this the wrong way entirely, I'm not positive.  And this is really my first real experience with using LINQ.

Comment: you'll be fine as long as you only use select statements

Comment: Ok, Thanks!  I'll give it a try.

Comment: and also, be careful not to execute heavy queries on production server, either make sure the query is fast, or do it on a backup database. but you already know that

Comment: I've got a copy of the production database on my local machine to test my queries thankfully.  So I can do some speed tests to make sure I don't do anything too stupid. :)

Comment: Be careful with some of this advice. You can't join an in-memory collection to a DB table without it first pulling back the entire DB table you're joining and performing the join in-memory. Check the generated SQL to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  I will make sure to be careful of that.